# Cannot redirect after insertion

Tags: node.js, express

I want to redirect to a url after the insert is success :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn").on("click", function() {
            $.post({
                url:"/track/admin/affecterMenusProfil",
                data:$("#frm").serialize()
            });
        });
    });

router.post("/affecterMenusProfil", function(req, res) {
    var profil = req.body.profil, menus = req.body.menus;
    connexion.query("delete from "+db.getPrefixNomTables()+"profil_menu where profil_id ="+profil, function (errDel, rowsDel) {
        if (errDel) 
            throw errDel;
        async.eachOf(menus, function(menu, position, cb) {
            connexion.query("insert into "+db.getPrefixNomTables()+"profil_menu(menu_id, profil_id) values("+menu+", "+profil+")", function (err, rows) {
                if (err) throw err;
                cb();
            });
        }, function() {
            res.redirect('/track/');
        });
    });
});
```

But at runtime there is no redirection : the page of insertion is still displayed ! So what is wrong in my codes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server won't redirect if your request from ajax.

In order to redirect you have to implement redirection logic on client side on success 
callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btn").on("click", function() {
            $.post({
                url:"/track/admin/affecterMenusProfil",
                data:$("#frm").serialize(), 
                success: function(response) {
                   window.location.href = response.url;
                }
            });
        });
});

router.post("/affecterMenusProfil", function(req, res) {
    var profil = req.body.profil, menus = req.body.menus;
    connexion.query("delete from "+db.getPrefixNomTables()+"profil_menu where profil_id ="+profil, function (errDel, rowsDel) {
        if (errDel) 
            throw errDel;
        async.eachOf(menus, function(menu, position, cb) {
            connexion.query("insert into "+db.getPrefixNomTables()+"profil_menu(menu_id, profil_id) values("+menu+", "+profil+")", function (err, rows) {
                if (err) throw err;
                cb();
            });
        }, function() {
            res.send({url: '/track/'});
        });
    });
});
```

You have to send URL from Server and redirect that URL from the client side as above.
I hope it will help you.